# How can this object reference itself

Tags: c

I've been tinkering with some code in a effort to understand OOP using c.
I really like this style and want to use it. The code sample works great if another class creates an instance of FooOBJ.

How can FooOBJ reference itself to change its own variables?
Do I need to make a copy of foo in the constructor or something like that or am I wandering away from the right way to use this methodology?

```
struct fooobj {
    int privateint;
    char *privateString;

};



FooOBJ newFooOBJ(){
    FooOBJ foo=(FooOBJ)malloc(sizeof(struct fooobj));
    bzero(foo, sizeof(struct fooobj));
    return foo;
}

void setFooNumber(FooOBJ foo,int num){
    if(foo==NULL) return;  /* you may chose to debugprint something
                *instead
                */
    foo->privateint=num;
}



void setmyself(int val)
{
   //this->privateint = val 
}
```

Comment: Better don't `typedef` pointer types, it's very confusing.

Comment: In C, functions that take no arguments should be declared with `(void)` in the argument list. Otherwise this is not a prototype, only a forward declaration that tells about the return type and not the arguments.

Comment: @Bo Persson. My current project is beginning to require the benifits of oop style. Sadly at the moment I don't have the spare time to learn c++ to a high enough standard required to complete my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, any function operating on an instance of your "class" will have to take a pointer to the instance. This happens automatically and implicitly in C++, but in C you'll have to pass a "this" pointer everywhere.

What this means is that your `setFooNumber` has the right signature for a "member function", whereas `setmyself` does not.

Comment: do you think it's a good or bad idea to be passing a this pointer around the place? I'm not clear from your answer how to achieve what I want.

Comment: @dubbeat: I think that passing the "this" pointer around is the *only reasonable way* to do what you want.

Comment: Cheers mate. I made a "this" pointer of type FooOBJ. Then in my "setmyself" function I grab the memory "this" is pointing to and change the value I want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason C++ and other OO languages have an implicit parameter to instance methods. The only way this can be done is if you explicitly pass a this pointer. A function doesn't have access to something that isn't declared in an appropriate scope: locally or globally (parameters being local).

To understand OOP in C, you'll need to understand how to simulate pure OO code in a procedural way.